# Why does apt-get install r-base install 3.2.3 instead of 3.4.0 in R?

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to install the latest version of R (3.4.0) due to some incompatibility issues with dowloading of a package called "Slam". I have downloaded the tar.gz file of 3.4.0 but there are some issues with the make file for installation.

I have uninstalled the r-base of 3.2.3. Now when I'm installing R again, I get the same version instead of the upgrade version. I even ran the `sudo apt-get update` command but in vain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to install from the CRAN repos not the ubuntu ones. add the key, then the repository, update and the apt-get

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: This is what I get when I execute the first instruction --> gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found

Comment: Thanks! I executed all but the first line. It worked :)